# How do I change the contents of list1 with the contents of list2?

Tags: java, liferay, java-7

I want to replace the modifiedDate values in listContextFiles by the values that corespand them from the same column of listAllDate, the result will be stored in list 3.

My code works perfectly but I do not want to use the setModifiedDate:

```
private List<DLFileEntry> getListFiles(List<DLFileEntry> listContextFiles,
        List<Date> listAllDate) {
    List<DLFileEntry> list3 = new ArrayList<DLFileEntry>();
    for (int i = 0; i <listContextFiles.size(); i++) {
        listContextFiles.get(i).setModifiedDate(listAllDate.get(i));
        list.add(listContextFiles.get(i));
    }
    return list3;
}
```

Comment: you can't go around calling `.setModifiedDate()` how would you then specify the new date?

Comment: `I do not want to use the setModifiedDate` - why? Do you prefer creating a new DLFileEntry instance?

Comment: They told me not to use the setModifiedDate. If it's not going to cause a problem I'll leave my code like that.

Comment: It is going to cause a problem if the elements of the original `listContextFiles` list is supposed to remain unchanged. If it's not supposed to remain unchanged, why create a 3rd list?

Comment: yes , the listContextFiles list is supposed to remain unchanged. what do I have to do?

Comment: @DarkMagic please see my answer below

Comment: @Eran Sorry, but your answer did not work. Cannot instantiate the type **DLFileEntry**. I work with liferay.

Comment: @DarkMagic Is `DLFileEntry` a class or an interface. If it's a class, does it implement the Cloneable interface?

Comment: @Eran DLFileEntry is an Interface. The extended model interface for the DLFileEntry service.

Comment: You want to change the *modified date* without calling the method that does *exactly* this? What kind of requirement is this? Why would you expect another method that has the same effect but a different name? And why would the name matter?